# Inaccessible type due to private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

`g++` is denying me access to a type, just because it happens to be a private grand-father. Does this make sense?

```
struct A {};

struct B : private A {};

struct C : B {
  void foo(A const& a) {}
};
```

Compiling this yields:

```
1:10: error: ‘struct A A::A’ is inaccessible
6:12: error: within this context
```

My point is: I never wanted to access `A` as an ancestor. In fact, if `A` is a private ancestor of `B`, shouldn't this be completely invisible to anybody but `B` (i.e. `C`)?

Of course, I could use `protected` inheritance but in my case it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to the injected class name from `A` hiding the global `A` inside `C`. Although `A` is visible, it is not accessible (since it is imported as private), hence the error. You can access `A` by looking it up in the global namespace:

```
void foo(::A const& a) {}
```

Answer (score 8):

if you declare it as follows it works

```
struct A {};

struct B : private A {};

struct C : B {
  void foo(::A const& a) {}
};
```

The error your seeing is do to name resolution not access. The ::A says look at the global namespace not my inherited nested class types. Also remember that private inheritance is just saying B has an A and IMOHO is a stupid language feature that should be avoided.

Comment: It's not a stupid feature at all; it allows one to restrict the inherited interface by individually picking out the functions to expose with `using`.

Comment: Which you could do with forwarder functions with out the feature and making the c++ inheritance model less cluttered.  private inheritance is not inheritance its composition and using the same semantics to accomplish two separate concepts is only confusing.

Comment: It's a difference between composition and private inheritance, because the latter allows you access to protected members of your father while the former doesn't.

Comment: I still wouldn't suggest using it except in that case.