# Why does protected inheritance cause dynamic_cast to fail?

Tags: c++, public, protected, dynamic-cast

I changed my C++ base class to be `protected` inheritance and my `dynamic_cast`(s) stopped working.

Why should changing the inheritance to `protected` change the behavior of `dynamic_cast`?

```
struct Base {
  static Base *lookupDerived(); // Actually returns a Derived * object.
};

struct Derived : protected /* Switch this to public to get it working */ Base {
 static void test() {
   Base *base = lookupDerived();

   if (dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base)) {
      std::cout << "It worked (we must be using public inheritance)." << std::endl;
   } else {
      std::cout << "It failed (we must be using protected inheritance)." << std::endl;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You as an outside user cannot access the protected or private members of a class. The same applies to protected or private inheritance. The authors of a class don't want outside users to access protected/private parent classes any more than they want outside users to access protected/private members.

One reason: Suppose the parent class has a non-virtual destructor. Deleting from an instance derived class from a base class pointer would result in undefined behavior. Making the parent class protected/private means you can't do this (see footnote).

Another reason: Suppose the authors of the class in question don't want outside users to have access to the public members of the parent class. One could use public inheritance (*is-a*) and demote those public interfaces to protected or private, but this would violate the Liskov substitution principle. Protected or private inheritance is not an *is-a* relationship. Those public methods become protected or private with protected or private inheritance. There's no problem with Liskov substitution because protected/private inheritance is not *is-a*.

Footnote: There is an ugly way around this: Use C-style casts. Outside users can cast a
derived class pointer to a base class pointer, even if the base class is not accessible. To me, that's yet another reason to compile with `-Wold-style-cast -Werror`.

Comment: but why does it fail when it's done inside the class?

Answer (score 3):

Private (or protected) inheritance is semantically different from public inheritance.
It is not a "is-a" relationship but a "implemented in terms of" relationship.

Meaning that you can't use a base class as a handle to a derived object.

Answer (score 2):

When you change your inheritance to protected, the relationship between your two classes is hidden from the exterior of the object.