# A trick to enable casting over non-public inheritances

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, protected, static-cast, upcasting

This is a followup related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62430684/1783163) where I investigated the problem and found that up- and downcasting seem to be working correctly over public inheritance relations. For example, this code does not even compile:

```
class A {
};

class B : protected A {
};

int main() {
  B b;
  static_cast<A*>(&b);
};
```

G++ gives the following error:

```
t.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cc:10:21: error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’
   10 |   static_cast<A*>(&b);
      |                     ^
```

However, I think I found the following trick to overcome this limitation. *We can cast inside the class, and then export the casting functionality as a public method:*

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
};

class B : protected A {
  public:
    A* getA() {
      return static_cast<A*>(this);
    };

    static B* fromA(A* a) {
      return static_cast<B*>(a);
    };
};

int main() {
  B b;

  // Does not even compile
  //std::cout << static_cast<A*>(&b);

  // works like charm
  std::cout << b.getA() << '\n';

  // works also in the reverse direction, although it needs a static method
  std::cout << B::fromA(b.getA()) << '\n';
};
```

I admit it is not very pretty. My tests (in more complex code) show it working, but I am still unsure.

Is it valid C++ code and correct practice?

Comment: Looks fine to me. The fact that `A` is a base class is declared as a `protected` implementation detail, and by making `getA` a member function, this implementation detail does not "leak" to the outside of the class. However, I would rethink my design if I needed this in the first place; implementation inheritance is not often the best tool for the job.

Comment: `protected` base class is one language construct that I have not found a good use for in my 20+ years of programming in C++.

Comment: @RSahu `Base` is a set of animals with a well-defined, narrow & stable set of operations on it. `Derived` is a set of dogs, with a yet more narrowed set of allowed operations on it, added by some extra functionality. You want to write as clean & optimized code as you can. How do you do it?

Comment: I do not see any benefit. In my mind, `B` either *is* `A`, or not. If it is not, `getA` makes no sense, if it is, it should inherit publicly.

Comment: @SergeyA What if `A` has some methods with unneeded interference with the methods of `B`? I do not want to give out the methods of `A` to the external world, but I want to use them from `B`.

Comment: But you do, by exposing `getA()`, which immediately gives access to all implementation details of A.

Comment: @SergeyA In this - minimal - example, yes it is so. In practice, the availability of `getA()` can be limited by making it protected/private and extended by friend classes. While the `friend` declaration has no effect to the availability of the base classes.

Comment: Well, for a differently structured code my opinion could be different :).

Comment: Body of `getA()` should be simply `return this;`.  No cast necessary.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica A `friend` can access protected/private base classes [(example)](https://godbolt.org/z/fb7hdY). Making the conversion function `protected` does not make it more accessible than `protected` inheritance (anything that can access the member function has the protected base visible).

Comment: Re the protected inheritance ... I haven't come across a real world use case for that yet either; asked about it here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/414504/65513

Comment: @Artyer Check the output again. gcc-9.3 compiled it, gcc-10.2 gave "inaccessible base" error. The c++ standard says that friendships affect only the local fields, not the parents.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica [[class.access.base\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.base#4.2): A base class `B` of `N` is accessible at R if R occurs in a member or friend of class `N`. Also the version was just a mistake on the config of the link, but you can try on multiple versions of different compilers.

Comment: @Artyer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62430684/1783163) my example code shows that it does not, at least casting does not work (externally).

Comment: @chev Thanks the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually `getA` is fine. `B` is choosing to expose the `A` in it. It can be simplified to `return this;`, the cast is unnecessary.

I have reservations about `fromA`, because it is implying that all `A`s are `B`s, which might not be true. You should limit the accessibility of `fromA` to places where you can prove all the `A`s are `B`s.

> Safe downcast may be done with `dynamic_cast`.

cppreference on [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Comment: I strongly dislike `dynamic_cast`. The essence of C/C++ is to make all testing in compile-time for performance in run-time.